# How to replace UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am newbie to react JS. How can I replace the UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to componentDidUpdate ?
Below is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDate();
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.updateDate();
  }

  updateDate() {
    if (typeof window !== null) {
      var base = Router.query.props[0];
      var quote = Router.query.props[1];
      this.props.GlobalStore.update_detail('pair_name', base + '/' + quote);
    }
  }
```

Why I am using this, because I need to rerender the component on changing URL parameters. I am using Next JS

Answer (score 1):

From React recomendation: [Replace UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)
You could:

**Replace**

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() {
     this.updateDate();
}
```

**By**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
     this.updateDate();
}
```

Comment: No, its not updating when only changing props in URL.